# How lost bids on ENS are credited back to my wallet ? Is it automatic or is there any manual process?

Tags: ens, auctions

I have lost few bids on ENS and so far the ethers that I have used for auction is not credited back. So I would like to know if there is any process to get back the ether or is this an automated process

Comment: Did you reveal your bids during the 48 hours reveal period?

Answer (score 1):

When another bidder outbids you, and you have revealed your bid, you are automatically credited your deposit (less a 0.5% fee).

This [credit does not show up as a transaction in blockchain explorers](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26521/why-is-my-balance-not-equal-to-the-sum-of-inbound-minus-the-sum-of-outbound-and). Etherscan, for example, shows it as an "internal transaction" because the value is transferred as part of a transaction that your account didn't initiate. As long as you revealed your bid successfully, you received your refund.

If you would like to confirm, you can post the account address you bid from and the name you were bidding on, and we can direct you to the specific link with the refund.

Comment: Does the bidder that outbid the previous person pay the gas to transfer the ETH back to the outbid person?

Comment: @AlecKriebel yes the new top bidder pays to refund the old top bidder. If you reveal and are not the new top bidder, you pay to transfer back your own deposit.

Comment: Can you please have a look? https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4831dbed82aaf859b484beae26ed8a24be2fce4c3912a5958d0b35950a72c90e I've called `unsealBid` during the `reveal` period, I was the only bidder and yet didn't receive any refund?

Comment: @MichalStefanow this question is specifically about *lost* bids. If you have a question about a bid you won, it's better to post it in a new question. The process is different.